# unable to store timings into vector

Tags: c++, timing

I'm writing a basic command shell in C++ and have been unable to resolve this issue, despite much searching. When I attempt to compile my program, I get the error:

> error: no matching function for call to
>   ‘std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>>::pop_back(std::__cxx11::string&)’
>   times.pop_back(tmp);

The code in question is:

```
int runArgs(char** args, std::vector<std::string> &histData, std::vector<std::string> &times) {

...
    // it's not a built-in command, so...
        else {
                auto before = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
                if(fork()) { // I'm the parent
                        wait(NULL);
                } else { // I'm the child
                        execvp(args[0], args);
                        // getting here means exec didn't work
                        std::cerr << "The program terminated because " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
                }
                auto after = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
                std::chrono::duration<double> dur = after - before;
                auto x = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(dur);
                std::string tmp = std::to_string(x.count());
                times.pop_back(tmp);
        }
```

It appears as though tmp has been declared as a pointer and I'm attempting to give my vector the wrong data type. However, I'm not using any pointers in this section of code. I've tried using a vector of doubles, but get the same sort of error. Is it something to do with having passed the vector by reference? Or do I not understand what chrono::duration::count is returning? Or is it something else entirely?

Comment: `...despite much searching` Did you happen to look up `pop_back` [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/pop_back/)?

Comment: Why not have a look at a [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/pop_back)?

Answer (score 2):

The  [`std::vector::pop_back()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/pop_back) method *removes* the last element from the `std::vector`. It does not take any input parameters, but you are trying to pass it one. That is what the compiler is complaining about.

To *add* a new element to the end of a `std::vector`, you need to use the [`std::vector::push_back()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) method instead:

```
times.push_back(tmp);
```

Comment: Well, I feel kinda dumb now... fixed the problem, and I greatly appreciate your advice. Sometimes you can't see the forest for the trees when you've been coding for too long.